# getResponseHeader('last-modified'); does not change value

Tags: php, javascript, getresponse

```
var page = 'data/appointments/<? echo $_SESSION['name']; ?><? echo $_SESSION['last']; ?>App.html';
var lM;
function checkModified(){
   $.get(page, function(a,a,x){
      var mod = x.getResponseHeader('last-modified');
      alert (lM);
      alert ("page" +mod);
});
}
```

when i alert the last-modified from my page, it outputs the same value, even when when i deleted all my cookies and cache , deleted the file from the server and replace it.

it still outputs one value

```
Tue , Oct 23, 2012 3:37:41 GMT
```

Comment: It's the server that will be setting this value. If it's setting it wrong then the server is where the problem lies. Not in your JavaScript.

Comment: i checked the value,and it changes constantly when i modify it. but the value on my alert is still the same

Comment: How are you checking it?

Comment: from the server, after modifiying the file , i check if the value from the server changes

Comment: `it changes constantly when i modify it` - How are you getting this value? Be specific.

Comment: Im checking it from the server. the listings from my file manager!

Comment: That is not necessarily the same as what your webserver is producing.

Comment: even checked it on file zila same changes occurs

Comment: `Last-Modified` from **HTTP response header** does not necessary equals to `Last Modified` from **file system**. It's your server (e.g. Apache) that decides what the response look like.